# WCF Service - Different datacontracts for SOAP + XML and JSON endpoints

Tags: xml, wcf, json, soap

I have a .NET 3.5 WCF Service which is currently a SOAP + XML service.
There is now a need to expose this same service to some clients who need the responses in JSON format.

While going over other SO questions about it and their answers, i believe that this in itself should be possible by having 2 different endpoints as explained [here](http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-restful-pox-json-and-soap-coexist.html)

However, i have a slightly bigger complication. The DataContracts to be exposed via the JSON service need to be altered i.e not all the properties that are currently exposed by the SOAP service are needed. The JSON object needs to expose only a subset of the properties.

**Is there is any way to have the DataContractJsonSerializer serializer omit certain fields which are decorated with the DataContract attribute?** This class is sealed so inheriting it is not an option. Do i need to write my own serializer here and if so, how would i go about instructing WCF to use my custom serializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are using `DataContractSerializer` and `DataContractJsonSerializer` on the same type they will always serialize same properties because these classes use same rules for serializtion. The easiest (and correct) way is simply define new service contract for second enpoint (or whole new service) and expose operations with new data contracts.